# Wildcards with Apache Directory and RewriteRule?

Tags: unix, apache, fuelphp

I'm trying to get FuelPHP to work on my server. I don't have access to use .htaccess file for RewriteRule. However, my host has allowed me to specify a part of the httpd.conf file.

The following works for what I want:

```
<Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/username/public>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

However, I need it to work for more than just "username" in there. **How can I use wildcards with this Directory so that it works for any values of "username" for a one-time solution?**

I found this advice on the [apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#directory), but I'm not sure how to get it to work with the `RewriteRule`.

Tried the following but it didn't work:

```
<Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/*/public>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

**Please help!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close with the apache manual:

```
<Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/*/public>
```

to

```
<Directory ~ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/.*/public">
```

Comment: can you tell whats wrong in this syntax. I get forbidden message:

Alias /salt "/var/cache/salt/master/minions/.*/files"

<Directory ~ "/var/cache/salt/master/minions/.*/files/">
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 1):

We found this message that addressed the problem we had, with no real solution provided: [How to use apache2 mod_rewrite within a Directory directive that uses wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358913/how-to-use-apache2-mod-rewrite-)

We ended up using the following solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d

RewriteRule ^(/sandbox/([^/]*)/public/.*)$ /sandbox/$2/public/index.php?$1 [PT,QSA]
```

The "PT" had to be added, as it is normally implied within directory blocks, and tells it to treat the target path as a URI instead of as a file path (which won't work since it's not getting the full local path). The QSA flag just makes sure your index.php gets handed all the information originally submitted.