# Wildcard in vhost directory path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following directive in one of my domain config files on Apache and for some reason it isn't working - the htaccess file is never detected so rewritten urls are coming up 404 (even though the htaccess file is copied from a site where it works).

```
<Directory ~ "/var/www/html/folder_.*/htdocs">
    # Allow htaccess files for this directory
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've based this on [Wildcards with Apache Directory and RewriteRule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203354/wildcards-with-apache-directory-and-rewriterule) which implies it should be working. I've found that sometimes people put this inside the `vhost` setting but in my instance its in the main body of one of the config files.

Why would the htaccess file not be detected?

I have also tried `<Directory ~ "^/var/www/html/folder_([^/]*)/htdocs">` which according to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory looks like it should work. I belive its because the regex isn't being detected at all - I can tell this because ~ in the following `<Directory ~ "/var/www/html/folder_demo/htdocs">` which definitely exists and without the ~/" works fine, isn't working with the ~ regex.

If it helps:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)    
Server built:   2023-03-08T17:32:54
```

Comment: Have you tried the non-regex variant? `<Directory /var/www/html/folder_*/htdocs>`

Comment: No and that has worked - thank you! Shame the question I referred to was advising not to do it ?? Thanks for the tip - it had looked like that wasn't the option.